# Почему не работают devtools для React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-chrome-devtools, expo

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

почему при открытии expo приложения

если в chrome перейти по адресу 'localhost:8081/debugger-ui' постоянно висит статус: Status: Waiting, press ⌘R in simulator to reload and connect.

при этом нажимаешь на кнопку внизу, чтобы перезагрузить приложение, он перезагружает приложение, но статус все равно не меняется

P.S использую эмулятор от android studio. Когда в меню expo нажимаешь j,чтобы открыть debugger, он все открывает и все работает, но этом debugger нет react-devtools и redux devtools

Answer (score 0):

Я проверил несколько пунктов прежде чем у меня заработало.

1. Нужно убедиться, что ваш браузер обновлен до последней версии.
2. Возможно, какие-то другие расширения мешают работе `react devtools`. Попробуйте их отключить.
3. Проверьте, включено ли расширение `react devtools` в окне управления расширениями.

Если ничего из вышеперечисленного вам не подошло, то возможно вы сможете найти ответ [здесь](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/27338).